# Angular FE running on IIS server: POST request to http://localhost:8080/api generates net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Tags: java, angular, spring, tomcat, iis

sorry for the long post in advance but I'm not such an expert (especilly in front-end development) and I will try to provide as much info as I can.
It's a couple of days I'm facing a problem after I deployed my webapp on production server.

The frontend is an Angular 8 application (deployed on IIS) that consumes REST APIs exposed by a Spring Boot application deployed on Apache Tomcat 8.5.47 (installed on the same production server).

If using any browser I go to www.mywebsite.com (just as an example to indicate that's my webapp registered domain) from the server itself, I have no problems at all and everything works properly.

The problem comes when I use a another computer rather than the server. In that case, I can see the homepage at www.mywebsite.com but as soon as the app tries to consume the REST APIs exposed for the Login I get POST http://localhost:8080/the-app-wish/api/login net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED in the Chrome console.

That's a screenshot of the error in Chrome console: [Chrome console error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sMa5i.jpg)

And this is one from the netwok tab: [Chrome network tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C27wM.jpg)

Let me provide some details and show you some code from the backend (as I said it's Spring Boot). 
In the application.properties I defined the following:

```
server.servlet.context-path=/the-app-wish
```

The controller for the Login has the following annotation:

`@CrossOrigin(origins = "*", maxAge = 3600) 
@RestController 
@RequestMapping("/api")`

And the login methos within the controller has this:

```
@PostMapping("/login")
```

In the WebSecurityConfig.class i have the following method to configure the patterns:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.cors().and().csrf().disable().
            authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/api/login", "/api/register", "/api/resetpwd", "/api/confirm-reset/**", "/api/auth/**").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(unauthorizedHandler).and()
            .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);

    http.addFilterBefore(authenticationJwtTokenFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
}
```

And now some details about the frontend (the Angular 8 app).
I defined a proxy.config.json as follows:

```
{
  "/": {
    "target": "http://localhost:8080",
    "secure": false,
    "logLevel": "debug"
  }
}
```

And I added a script in the index.html file as follow, in case the base url to the api differs between dev and prod environments (but that's not yet the case):

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Studio Scordia</title>
    <base href="/">

    <script type="text/javascript">
      var cfgApiBaseUrl = "http://localhost:8080/the-app-wish";
      /*
      DEV: http://localhost:8080/the-app-wish*
      PROD: http://localhost:9000/the-app-wish
       */
      window.cfgApiBaseUrl = cfgApiBaseUrl;
    </script>

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
  </head>
  <body>
    <app-root></app-root>
  </body>
</html>
```

Finally that's my service consuming the login (and others) REST API from the backend:

```
const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' })
};

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthService {
  private BASE_URL = window["cfgApiBaseUrl"] + "/api";

  private loginUrl = `${this.BASE_URL}/login`;
  private registerUrl = `${this.BASE_URL}/register`;
  private resetpwdUrl = `${this.BASE_URL}/resetpwd`;
  private confirmResetpwdUrl = `${this.BASE_URL}/confirm-reset`;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  attemptAuth(credentials: AuthLoginInfo): Observable<JwtResponse> {
    return this.http.post<JwtResponse>(this.loginUrl, credentials, httpOptions);
  }

  signUp(info: SignUpInfo): Observable<string> {
    return this.http.post<string>(this.registerUrl, info, httpOptions);
  }

  resetPwd(info: ResetPwdInfo): Observable<string> {
    return this.http.post<string>(this.resetpwdUrl, info, httpOptions);
  }

  confirmResetPwd(token: string, newPassword: ChangePassword): Observable<string> {
    return this.http.post<string>(`${this.confirmResetpwdUrl}/${token}`, newPassword, httpOptions);
  }

}
```

I tryed many suggestions found on the internet. Adding a web.config in the dist folder of the Angular 8 app as the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <configuration>
    <system.webServer>
      <rewrite>
        <rules>
          <rule name="Angular Routes" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url=".*" />
            <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
             <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
             <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
             <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/(api)" negate="true" />
            </conditions>
           <action type="Rewrite" url="/" />
          </rule>
       </rules>
      </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
  </configuration>
```

But it didn't help to solve the error I get on POST requests. 
I also tried to deploy both FrontEnd and Backend on Tomcat, even If i read somewhere that's not a good practice. Anyhow, that didn't work as, probably, I was not able to configure properly IIS.
I tried to use the isapi_redirect.dll to redirect requests for the TomCat server from IIS as explained [here](https://tomcat.apache.org/connectors-doc/webserver_howto/iis.html) but the error didn't go away.
What am I doing wrong? Is that something I could solve somehow with the proxy.config.json file in the frontend? I attempted something on that way too but I didn't succeeded. I don't know anymore what I should try and as I'm not that senior in development yet I decided to ask here to someone surely more expert than I am. Unfortunately I'm the only developer in the firm I work for so I have no other colleagues to ask to. So, please, any suggestion would be more than appreciated. Thank you all in advance.

Answer (score 0):

make sure post works via POSTMAN or smth similar.

the whole scenario is simple, server should accept the request without much of configuration, the only important thing if it is under different port or domain is CrossOrigin access.

what I can see in one of your screenshots is that your frontent seems to be on **www._____.org** and backend on **localhost**

localhost for browser means your machine, and error indicates that server is not running, or the endpoint you are calling is not up.

Comment: TomCat Is running in production for sure, otherwise how could everything work when I browser to the webapp from the production server? Postman Is something I already checked before and when i use It on production It confirms what i say. I think the issue Is related to the fact that in my angular service i make calls to localhost:8080. Shall i change those URLs? If so, where should they point to? Is the problem somewhere else?

Comment: Which url you should use in browser to access the prod rest API? If it is on server somewhere, it shouldnt be local host.